# Format date from mysql query with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an sql query that I use to display the news section of my website.

I would really love for the dates to be presented as "2nd January, 2012" however as I am selecting all fields from 5 tables I don't know where to put my formatting requirements (I am not selecting individual fields).

My query is below:

```
$query_newsheadlines = "
SELECT *
FROM 
  NewsArticles, 
  NewsArticleCategories, 
  NewsArticlePhotos,
  NewsCategories, 
  NewsPhotos
WHERE
  NewsArticles.id = NewsArticleCategories.newsArticleID 
  AND NewsArticles.id = NewsArticlePhotos.newsArticleID
  AND NewsArticlePhotos.newsPhotoID = NewsPhotos.id
  AND NewsArticleCategories.newsCategoryID = NewsCategories.id
  AND NewsCategories.SectionID = 201
ORDER BY NewsArticles.publishDate DESC";
```

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

**update the column my date is located in is NewsArticles.publishDate**

Comment: I see an errant spare comma after `201,` after formatting it.

Comment: In which table do you have the date column  ?

Comment: Generally it is _not_ a good idea to `SELECT *` in production code, especially in a JOIN query.  Even though you're pulling loads of cols from loads of tables, it is recommend to list them individually and alias them where the names collide.

Comment: That said, you _can_ do `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(thedatecol, '%D %M, %Y') AS yourformatteddate FROM.....` listing it after the `*`. It duplicates the date cols as already listed in the `*`.

Comment: I tried this idea and even though it seems like it should it doesn't work.

Comment: Why? do you get the wrong formatting? Is the column not present? Does MySQL give an error?

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify what column do you want to be formatted (*just don't be lazy on specifying the column*). Use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%D %M, %Y')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/5433)

Other Source(*s*)

- [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: I don't use * to be lazy - I am trying to reduce the amount of code on my page. I have about 50 columns I require so it's much more succinct to use *.